# How can i split a string with words separated by double comma?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
String word = textBox1.Text;
string[] test = word.Split(",,");
```

If it's with one `word.Split(",");` it will work fine.
But in this case the string is in format: `hello,,hi,,50,,70`
And I want to parse it so in the array I will have:

```
hello hi 50 70
```

> Getting error on: word.Split(",,");
>
> Error  2   Too many characters in character literal
>
> Error  3   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error  4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: Your code and error messgae do not match - are you sure your code isnt really `word.Split(',,');` (ie, a single quote not a double)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead

```
string[] test = word.Split(new string[] { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if *double* ',' is a real deriver; probaly you have just *empty fields*. To skip these fields, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string source = "hello,,hi,,50,,70"
string[] result = source.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also split it by 1 comma only, then remove the empty array

```
string[] test = word.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```